# The converter specified on "enum" does not derive from JsonConverter or have a public parameterless constructor( Swagger | Enum)

Tags: c#, json, .net, swagger, openapi

I am trying to include swagger in our jsonapi api.
I have included the necessary packages , mentioned from the JsonApiDotNetCore team.

While adding swagger hooks in Program.cs , I am trying to generate the openapi document.

To be specific I have something like the below in the `Program.cs`

```
var sw = app.Services.GetRequiredService<ISwaggerProvider>();
OpenApiDocument doc = sw.GetSwagger("v1");
doc.SerializeAsJson(OpenApiSpecVersion.OpenApi3_0);
```

I am getting the below error during the generation

***The converter specified on 'x.x.x.enum'
does not derive from JsonConverter or have a public parameterless constructor.***

The enum that is mentioned is as below

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum Enum
{
  [EnumMember(Value = "Value1")]
  Value1

  ...

  ...
}
```

Do you have any idea of why is swagger breaking ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mixup of System.Json.Text and NewtonSoft.Json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer , fixed this by adding the below line while configure services.

```
.AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()));
```